# How can I push the button on the bottom of the list by clicking on it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to make a button go to the bottom of the list by clicking on it in JavaScript. I'm a bit of a noob and I didn't find anything regarding buttons swapping positions.

For example if I click on `BTN2` I want the order to be: `BTN1`, `BTN3`, `BTN4`, `BTN2`

So far I don't know how to even begin.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="attp">
    <p class="textbox">ATTP</p>
    <ul>
      <li><button>BTN1</button></li>
      <li><button>BTN2</button></li>
      <li><button>BTN3</button></li>
      <li><button>BTN4</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you require you need to attach an event handler to each button. From there you can retrieve the closest `li` element to the button which was clicked, then move it to the bottom of the `ul` that contains it by calling `append()`. Here's a working example:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('.container ul');

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    ul.append(e.target.closest('li'));
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="attp">
    <p class="textbox">ATTP</p>
    <ul>
      <li><button>BTN1</button></li>
      <li><button>BTN2</button></li>
      <li><button>BTN3</button></li>
      <li><button>BTN4</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you're new to JS here's some required reading on the functions being used here, as you will need to understand their purpose and usage:

- [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Element.closest()` and `Element.append()` methods:

```js
const attpULs = document.querySelectorAll(".attp ul");

attpULs.forEach((elUL) => {

  elUL.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    const elBtn = evt.target.closest("button");
    if (!elBtn) return; // Not clicked on a button. Do nothing
    const elLI = elBtn.closest("li"); // Get buton's LI parent
    elUL.append(elLI); // Move button's LI element
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div class="attp">
  <p class="textbox">ATTP</p>
  <ul>
    <li><button type="button">BTN1</button></li>
    <li><button type="button">BTN2</button></li>
    <li><button type="button">BTN3</button></li>
    <li><button type="button">BTN4</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The above will also work for dynamically generated LI elements since the **event is delegated** from the parent UL and searches for the button using the `Event.target.closest()`.

Refer to: [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)